# Get only the two lists with the most similarity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two-dimensional list. I would like to get the two elements from list_j, i.e. the two lists that have the highest agreement with list_g. I've tried something, but how do I get the two lists that match the most?

```
list_j = [[100,2,3], [4,98,99], [5,99,98]]

list_g = [100,99,98]

import difflib
list_ratio = []
for element_g in list_j:
  sm=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,element_g,list_g)
  list_ratio.append(sm.ratio())

print(list_ratio)

[OUT] [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666]
```

In this example, the last element then 1 or 2 has the most similarity. How could I get them?

Comment: By similarity you mean that they have the most similar items at the same position? Are all lists of the same length? An d do you compare all of them with a specific list_g?

Comment: By equality I mean the items in the same position. And no, the lists are not all of the same length, but you could say that you only pay attention to the 10 first elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to determine similarity for real number valued lists of the same length is with the [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) metric. Python's math library allows us to calculate this metric if we iterate over the lists.

```
import math
list_j = [[100,2,3], [4,98,99], [5,99,98]]
list_g = [100,99,98]
```

The following function will return a similarity score based on the RMSE, along with the index of that list within `list_j`, as a two-dimensional list.

```
def similarity(list_j, list_g):
    dists = [list() for i in range(len(list_j))]
    for i_j,j in enumerate(list_j):
        for i in range(len(j)):
            dist = (j[i] - list_g[i])**2
            dists[i_j].append(dist)
        dists[i_j] = [math.sqrt(sum(dists[i_j])), i_j]
    return dists
```

Given that we want to find the two lists in `list_j` that are the most similar, the following function returns those lists in the order of their similarity.

```
def similar_two(list_j, dists):
    list_js = sorted(dists)
    list_j_1 = list_js[0][1]
    list_j_2 = list_js[1][1]
    return list_j[list_j_1], list_j[list_j_2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `sort` the items in `list_j` in descending order based on their similarity `ratio` with `list_g`, then to get the top two similar sub-list from `list_j` simply use slicing:

```
s = SequenceMatcher(b=list_g)
sorted(list_j, key=lambda j: s.set_seq1(j) or -s.ratio())[:2]
```

Result:

```
[[5, 99, 98], [100, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the items to be at the same position, then your can try this function:

```
def most_similar(long_list, ref_list):
    d={tuple(i):sum(1 for p in range(len(ref_list)) if i[p]==ref_list[p]) for i in long_list}
    return d

temp=most_similar(list_j, list_g)

res={k: v for k, v in sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

This will result to a dictionary with the similarity for each sublist sorted by degree of similarity. From this result, you can select the items you want, depending on your conditions (degree of similarity, count of items for each degree, etc):

```
>>> print(res)

{(5, 99, 98): 2, (100, 2, 3): 1, (4, 98, 99): 0}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Short question, how can I set it to return the two most similar ones to me, for example? Or the three most similar? Sorry, but I still don't really see where I state how many highest similar lists I would like to return.

Comment: You want the 2 first of the most similar, or all items that belong to most similar and second most similar?

Comment: For example, if I have three lists, one has 100% the other 66% and the other 33% and I state that I want the two lists with the highest equality, list one should be output with 100% and list 2 with 66% all elements contained in the list